# Thread call member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, winapi

I need to call a member function of a class through thread but I don't want to use Boost library binding concept and the class I have to use doesn't have any static function to help out. I tried to use `STL mem_fun_ref` but I received a compile time error.

```
 base b;
 handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0,  LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(bind2nd(mem_fun_ref(&base::show), &b)),           
                          NULL, NULL, &dword);

class B{
public:
  void show(){
    cout << "show";
  }
};
```

Comment: The two answers you have are both right, but note that you should generally use `_beginthreadex()` rather than `CreateThread()`, otherwise the CRT may not be initialized properly for the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `CreateThread()` but looks like a C-style interface to thread creation: you probably won't be able to pass through a function object. Most likely, the start function type is the moral equivalent of

```
extern "C" typedef void (*entry_funciont)(void*);
```

possibly with a few extra parameters and returning something different than `void`. You'll need a forwarding function to recover your function object for which you'll need to know the exact type of the function object passed to the `CreateThread()` function as the "user data" (I'd guess where you pass `NULL` right after you function object. You could use something along the lines of this:

```
struct entry_base {
    virtual ~entry_base() {}
    virtual void call() = 0;
};
template <typename Fun>
struct entry
    : entry_base {
    Fun fun;
    entry(Fun fun): d_fun(fun) {}
    void call() {
        this->d_fun();
        delete this;
    }
};
template <typename Fun>
entry_base* make_entry(Fun fun) {
    return new entry<Fun>(fun);
}

extern "C" void call_entry(void* entry) {
    static_cast<entry_base*>(entry)->call();
}
```

... which can then be used something like this:

```
base* b = ...; // you can't use a local object here!
handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0,
                      LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(&call_entry),
                      make_entry(bind2nd(mem_fun_ref(&base::show), &b)),           
                      NULL, &dword);
```

Note that I'm speculating somewhat about the interface to `CreateThread()`, i.e., the user data pointer may very well go into a different location. However, binding to a pointer to a local object is almost certainly not going to work: this object is likely to go out of scope while the thread is running and it would remove the basis for the object running.

Comment: Create Thread is WinAPI function, the question is tagged as winapi.

Comment: @IuriCovalisin: yes, I noted that: you don't imply that I have to know WinAPI to provide something I consider helpful, do you? The question is also tagged C++ and that's where I came across it. I *think* my answer does apply although some of the details need to be meddled with. From a cusory look, my guesses were actually all correct...

Answer (score 1):

This is C WinAPI function, here's the declaration:

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  _In_opt_   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
  _In_       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_opt_   LPVOID lpParameter,
  _In_       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_opt_  LPDWORD lpThreadId
);
```

The problem is the LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE type defines a pointer to callback function, and not C++ method that has "hidden" this parameter.

Here's good example how to bypass it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/09/49028.aspx

```
class SomeClass {
 ...
 static DWORD CALLBACK s_ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
 {
  return ((SomeClass*)lpParameter)->ThreadProc();
 }
 DWORD ThreadProc()
 {
  ... fun stuff ...
 }
};
```